RuntimeError: Cannot create Binding object for non-Ruby caller
I have been using the answers from How to Make Or Reference a Null Ruby Binding For Eval for almost a year. Then I updated Ruby to v3.2.2.
Now, the following code throws: RuntimeError: Cannot create Binding object for non-Ruby caller:
class NullBinding < BasicObject
  def min_binding
    ::Kernel
      .instance_method(:binding)
      .bind_call(self)
  end
end

class Whatever
  def self.evaluate(string)
    eval string, NullBinding.new.min_binding, __FILE__, __LINE__
  end
end

The string parameter value being passed to Whatever::evaluate probably does not matter because I do not think it is looked at. The call that blows up is:
self.class.evaluate "->(a, b) { [b.last_modified, b.date] <=> [a.last_modified, a.date] }"


This might be a bug or regression. I'd suggest searching for a bug report here, or reporting it if there isn't one. To get unblocked for now, I think you can use ::Kernel.binding to directly call that method, instead of that bind_call trick. There's no behavioural difference, as far as I can tell.

What would that call look like?

Literally just ::Kernel.binding instead of ::Kernel.instance_method(:binding).bind_call(self)

Ah, turns out there is a difference, executing Ruby code in the context of that binding still lets you call methods on Kernel like raise or puts.

What about self.eval string, binding, __FILE__, __LINE__ for the body of self.evaluate?

That snippet doesn't match what you show in your question body, which is val string, NullBinding.new.min_binding, __FILE__, __LINE__.

Quite right. I just want to be able to evaluate the string passed to evaluate. I do not care if the implementation resembles the previous code.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The change is here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/5567/files.
It appears this was very intentional.
To circumvent this while still obtaining the same result (as far as I can tell) we can take a bit more of an obtuse approach by introducing Kernel into the class and then undefining all of its instance methods excepting binding
class NullBinding < BasicObject 
  include ::Kernel 
  (::Kernel.instance_methods(false) + 
   ::Kernel.private_instance_methods(false)  - 
     [:binding]).each(&method(:undef_method))

  def min_binding
    binding
  end
end 

This is awkward but it appears to offer a functional equivalent to what I previously provided as a NullBinding in the aforementioned post.

Related Ruby Bug for this change: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18487
